# Unresolved reference 'pyspark' on pycharm

Tags: python, pyspark, pycharm

I am a begginer programming in python and I just wanted to import some features from pyspark package. The problem is that, when I write this:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import HashingTF, IDF, Tokenizer
```

it is said "Unresolved reference pyspark". Why is that?

Here are the steps I followed to create the proyect:

1. New project using the interpreter python 3.6
2. New python file called    "main.py"
3. Once the error pop-up I choose "Install pyspark package" but it does not solve it.

Can anyone help me out please?

[image]

Comment: may be try this https://medium.com/@gauravmshah/pyspark-on-intellij-with-packages-auto-complete-5e3208504707

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `pyspark` in your Python library?

From the screenshot, it looks like you've got the zip file (`pyspark...tar.gz`), but you need to unzip it prior to use.

The screenshot shows your Python library root as `python3.6`. Try extracting `pyspark...tar.gz` to `python3.6/site-packages` and see if that fixes your problem.

In addition, here's a cool tutorial using PySpark+Jupyter:
https://blog.sicara.com/get-started-pyspark-jupyter-guide-tutorial-ae2fe84f594f

Comment: I tried unzipping the spark zip in python3.6/site-packages but did not work